# SVG <object>'s child elements odd behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I don't know if this is a bug, undefined behavior or what. But when loading an SVG in with the `<object>` element, JS and CSS are unpredictable when it comes to accessing child elements of that SVG. Best I show and example:

Here we have our `test.svg`:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="myrect" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

And our `test.html`:

```
<object
    style = "max-width:300px"
    type  = "image/svg+xml"
    data  = "test.svg" />
```

Now when I load the page I can see the black rectangle. When I execute `document.querySelector("svg")` in the console it comes up null. However when I inspect element on the page and see that there is indeed an SVG in the dom, I execute that command again and this time it returns the svg.

Thus, without any modification the DOM managed to change itself for no reason. What is supposed to happen?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J74ch.png)

### Update regarding what browser I was using

I was using Brave Version 1.31.88 Chromium: 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) while getting the above results. My firefox browser seems to provide a different result, that is the JS never has access to the SVG regardless if I inspect element or not.

### Possible workaround (js only)

Using the getSVGDocument() function, I have the ability to modify the style.

```
document.querySelector("object").getSVGDocument().querySelector("#myrect").style="fill:red";
```

The above code works so long that you don't inspect element on the rectangle. Works all the time in firefox.

*HOWEVER* the above solution only works on a fresh download of the object data. If you try to refresh, the above script will not work...

**OH MY LORD I DIDN'T REALIZE THE RABBIT HOLE OF CHROME/MOZILLA BUGS I'VE JUST ENTERED**

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll("svg")`

Comment: No need to use `<object>` here, just add the SVG directly in the HTML. All browsers support this. Then you can query it via JS and style it via CSS without problems.

Comment: Nothing. Any JS command ignores the existence of the SVG until I inspect element.

Comment: @cloned That wont work as the SVG can sometimes be huge, hundreds of lines. Pasting it over and over again would be a nightmare, especially when the SVG needs updating.

Comment: You don't copy-paste the SVG, you use something like `<?php include("/icons/icon-cart.svg"); ?>` if you use PHP. There are ways to do this for every language you use. Also checkout [this post](https://css-tricks.com/pretty-good-svg-icon-system/)

Comment: @cloned That is by all means a valid workaround. But its inefficient; if I use the SVG 5 times on a page that means the browser has to download 5 times as much SVG as it needs too. I'm looking for a frontend-only solution (one that can work without a backend server).

Comment: Nah, not really, your HTML is getting compressed before it is sent. And since SVG is just text, it can be compressed really, really great. So this is not really a workaround but a valid solution you should really consider this. It's like sending it only once to the client, the browser then does the magic.

Comment: you need to wait for the object element's load event.

Comment: You could load the external SVG with a Web Component, and inject it in the DOM. The same SVG will be loaded from the cache. You still need to work in your code you want applied **after** load (like Robert said) See: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd